# Attach document from Sharepoint online to an email

Tags: sharepoint-online

What would be the best way for Sharepoint online users to attach documents from the Sharepoint site to an email? Preferably using the "attach file" option from Outlook/Owa. I know Microsoft recommends to offline-sync the files with Onedrive for business, but that has a 5000 item limit and you risk that the synchronization fails. I'd love to use a mapped network drive, but they lose connection on each restart and it's not even enough to log in to your sharepoint site, you have to click "open in explorer" to make them work again. I've seen here some similar questions with efforts to refresh the connection in order to keep it alive, but it doesn't seem to work.

Has anyone got a satisfactory solution to this seemingly obvious user request?

Comment: My company had the same need. We use a Sharepoint App (Slim Companion email manager) that allows us to select documents in Sharepoint and attach them to an email.

Answer (score 0):

I loathe sending documents via email because as soon as you do, you run into version difference issues easily. I'd recommend using the Send To option from the item context menu to Email a link to the file.

This will open a new email window, assuming you have Outlook running, and put in the link to the file in question. Enforce the behavior of viewing/modifying the source of the file, not a copy that can then be forwarded or modified and not reflect the actual document.

Comment: I fully agree! Of course the users should never attach documents when sending email internally, but if they want to send a file to a client or other external contact, they still need this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Now :) you can use Delve.
 It allows you to attach documents from SharePoint sites to OWA emails directly. It basically introduces a number of options for integrating mailboxes and SPO documents. If your tenant is set to "FirstRelease", Delve should be enabled there already.

For more information on Delve:
https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Delve-for-Office-365-admins-54f87a42-15a4-44b4-9df0-d36287d9531b
http://blogs.office.com/2014/03/11/introducing-codename-oslo-and-the-office-graph/

Answer (score 0):

OOTB it requires the user to download one or more files, open a new email in Outlook and select the downloaded files from the browser's download location.
This works but it is quite cumbersome.

There are SharePoint Add-ins that provide this capability. Some are free and some even support multiple browsers. Check out https://store.office.com/search.aspx?productgroup=SharePoint&qu=email

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement recently. What I ended up doing is:

1. Go to the SharePoint Library you'd like to attach files from
2. Open the library with file explorer (option in the ribbon)
3. Add the location to favorites in the file explorer
4. When you want to attach the file to an email from that library, choose "Browse This PC..." and then the library from favorites

NOTE: This works fine if you use Outlook on desktop or Outlook Online in IE. It doesn't work on Outlook Online in Chrome as much as I tested it...

Answer (score 0):

We have created an Outlook AddIn that is working cross platform/device. The Add-In is free to all small teams up to 5 persons. The free version has no restrictions, no ads and support full functionality which includes:

- Save emails and attachments to SharePoint, Teams and OneDrive
- Capture email properties automatically
- Attach files to new email including converting to PDF on -the-fly
- Works cross platform and device, i.e. Windows, macOS, iOS, Android, Web

It can be downloaded from https://axpoint.com or Microsoft [AppSource](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa200001539?tab=overview)

Hope this free version can help you being more productive